# Lookup Excel Column, Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having a bit of a struggle.

I really have no clue how to do this type of lookup.

I want to lookup the date in column, find the value 1 within that column and return the name on the same row to the left.

Is it possible to do this or do I need to redesign the table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX`/`MATCH` can help you:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A12,INDEX(A1:G8,0,MATCH(A11,1:1,0)),0))
```

Adjust ranges to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Tried to use index and match. But see now where I went wrong :)